# Countifs alternative in PowerQuery for MS PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a bit complicated PowerQuery query which has many steps. Within these steps I have a date, team and conditions as below (not actual data)

[image]

So the challenge is that I want to count the Pass number for each team for each day and then create another count for Pass and Fail and then it will be used in so many calculations which I can handle later.

I have tried many options, like for example grouping, but it was so confusing because as I mentioned before, the query has so many columns and calculations now. I could successfully solve the issue by creating DAX measure, but the issue here that I need to calculate the average outcome which is not possible to because I couldn't also average the measure of the outcome. So I have no other option but to make the countif though PowerQuery.

Appreciate your help and ideas.

Raw data as text is [here in google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17LIy4nhdZutfq6xUCf7QL_alSkAVR9yF45BfvKIdk0c/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Can you show what your expected results should look like?

Comment: Why can't you average your measure within the desired grouping?

Comment: @DavidBacci i have updated the google sheet with the table of the result, thank you so much

Comment: @Marcus every time i try to average the measure, it doesnt show up, only the columns in the table. i tried AVERAGEX with VALUE but still no luck :(

Comment: Do you need the zero values in your end result?

Comment: I think some of your dates are wrong. I don't believe they were playing in `0203`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your dates showing the year `0203` is a typo and should be `2023`

Not sure exactly what you want for output, but you should be able to adapt the below.

The solution seems to be a simple grouping with a count of the number of passes and/or fails.

The below code generates a separate column for passes and fails per team and date.

It is not sorted in the original order, but that could be added if necessary.

```
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Previous Step", {"Date", "Team"}, {
        {"Pass", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[#"PASS/FAIL"], each _ = "Pass")), Int64.Type},
        {"Fail", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[#"PASS/FAIL"], each _ = "Fail")), Int64.Type}
    })
```

Using your data table from the Google sheet (after correcting the year):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Team", type text}, {"PASS/FAIL", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date", "Team"}, {
        {"Pass", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[#"PASS/FAIL"], each _ = "Pass")), Int64.Type},
        {"Fail", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[#"PASS/FAIL"], each _ = "Fail")), Int64.Type}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

***Note** If you require that all teams show on all dates even if they didn't play, one merely creates a new table containing all dates and teams; and then Joins that to the original table, as in the code below:*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Team", type text}, {"PASS/FAIL", type text}}),

//If you need to show all teams on all dates, even if they didn't play on a date
//we merely create a blank table (dates and teams), and execute an outer join.
//then remove the original date/team columns before the grouping.
    #"Date List" = List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Date]),
    #"All Teams" =  List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Team]),
    Blank = Table.FromColumns(
                {List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Date List", each List.Repeat({_}, List.Count(#"All Teams")))),
                List.Repeat(#"All Teams", List.Count(#"Date List"))},
                type table[dates=date, teams=text]),
    join = Table.Join(Blank,{"dates","teams"}, #"Changed Type",{"Date","Team"}, JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(join,{"Date", "Team"}),

    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"dates", "teams"}, {
        {"Pass", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[#"PASS/FAIL"], each _ = "Pass")), Int64.Type},
        {"Fail", (t)=>List.Count(List.Select(t[#"PASS/FAIL"], each _ = "Fail")), Int64.Type}
    }),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"dates", Order.Ascending}, {"teams", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution but what about showing AR on 2/2/2023 with zero? OP didn't clarify if these are definitely required though but did show them in expected output.

Comment: @DavidBacci Good point. Hopefully he will clarify. But it should be easy to add those rows if necessary for the teams that didn't play on a particular date.

Comment: it looks logic but for some strange reason it says that date can not be found :(Expression.Error: The column 'Date' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Date

Comment: im sorry i mistakenly added the data to be 0203

Comment: @egflame That means exactly what it says. Which step first shows the error? The code works on your presented data. Perhaps your real data is different? Different case? Space in the column header?

Comment: it worked so well with the data i provided, i will try to implement the code in my original data. thank you so much

Comment: @egflame Let me know if you run into problems implementing it with your real data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld tbh im struggling with it since my query grow so much  grouping in this case is bit confusing.  plus its confidential data cant share it with others for compliance purposes :/

Comment: @egflame You should be able to create an example which replicates your problem, using fake data instead of real data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the zeroes in your final output, you'll need to do a cross join to bring in combinations not present in the original.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtQ31DcyMDJW0lFyDAISAYnFxUqxOigSrn44JFxcgYRbYmYOuoSfD7KEkb4RilEkSeA0Cr8E3LlIEmDnEpYw1jfWNzAywDSKIgmcduCUQI0PJAnU+CDGKNSwotwOiFGxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Team = _t, #"PASS/FAIL" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type text}, {"Team", type text}, {"PASS/FAIL", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date", "Team"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    Custom1 = List.Distinct( #"Grouped Rows"[Date]),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Custom1, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Date"}, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Team", each List.Distinct( #"Grouped Rows"[Team])),
    #"Expanded Team" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Team"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Team", {"Date", "Team"}, #"Grouped Rows", {"Date", "Team"}, "Expanded Team", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Expanded Team" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Expanded Team", {"Count"}, {"Count"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Expanded Team",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Count"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Stepping through the code:

1. Group by date and team and create a count:

[image]

2. Get a distinct list of dates
3. Convert to table
4. Add column for a cross join with all teams (to get zero values later)
5. Expand
6. Merge back to the grouped step to pull in the previous grouped values.
7. Replace nulls with 0

You can amend this for your other question by simply filtering for pass before you do the grouping.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. for this solution i tried it but for some reason the code is broken at the step of expanding the team from the merge step. can you please clarify what was the merge for ? and i cant see the PASS/FAIL in the code, is that ok?

Comment: Paste my code into a blank query and it works exactly as described including sample data. You can then click through each step to study it and apply to your own problem.

Comment: this code worked so well also. i will try to apply it to my query. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just add column, custom column

```
= 1
```

then click select Pass/Fail column, transform .. pivot .. and choose the new column as values column

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 1),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[PassFail]), "PassFail", "Custom", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```